# d3 chart on click table creation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3 I created a bar chart for a data, on clicking the a bar, I would like to create a table for that clicked data. I have passed the data but the table is not generating. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: please show us some sample code

Answer (score 0):

You must use d3's built in event handling.

I would get started by reading about `selection.on`. From the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on):

> ## selection.on(typenames[, listener[, capture]])
>
> Adds or removes a listener to each selected element for the specified event typenames. The typenames is a string event type, such as click, mouseover, or submit; any DOM event type supported by your browser may be used. The type may be optionally followed by a period (.) and a name; the optional name allows multiple callbacks to be registered to receive events of the same type, such as click.foo and click.bar. To specify multiple typenames, separate typenames with spaces, such as input change or click.foo click.bar.